# Зафиксировать кнопку внизу

Tags: android, android-layout

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне расположить Button в самом низу экрана? Аналогично `position: fixed; bottom: 0` в CSS. Пробовал через FrameLayout, но не особо получилось.

Вот сама кнопка (её нужно разместить и закрепить в самом низу):

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

а вот весь остальной код с различными элементами:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:text="Ваш баланс:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:text="0 ₽"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:background="@drawable/nav_main_menu_stroke"
                android:text="Все"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Магазины"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Рестораны"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:background="#F4F7F9"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Магазин -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/goods_item_style"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@mipmap/per"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Перекрёсток"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Крупнейшая российская сеть супермаркетов."
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="15% кэшбэка"
                    android:textColor="#E15C2F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Магазин -->

            <!-- Магазин -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/goods_item_style"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@mipmap/pyat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Пятёрочка"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Российская сеть продовольственных магазинов «у дома»."
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="7% кэшбэка"
                    android:textColor="#E15C2F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Магазин -->

            <!-- Магазин -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/goods_item_style"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Семёрочка"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Магазин низких цен."
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="50% кэшбэка"
                    android:textColor="#E15C2F"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Магазин -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: попробуйте в качестве главного контейнера ConstraintLayout: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет закреплена с самого низа все время:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"
    app:subtitleTextColor="?colorPagerYellow"
    app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
    app:titleTextColor="?colorPagerYellow" />




<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarDrawer">


</FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам порекомендовал почитать про https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview для работы со списками.
Или можете попробовать сделать так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLAyout ...>
сюда можно вставить ваш корневой LinearLayout
   <LinearLayout android:layout_above="@+id/button"
      ...>
   ...
   </LinearLayout>
   <Button android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```