# Как добавить пустое пространство в scrollview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

В общем, имеется ScrollView в приложении на android. В него помещается ListView.

В нижней части экрана находятся кнопки.

Как добавить пустое пространство после списка элементов, чтобы последний элемент прокручивался выше позиций кнопок?

margin/padding не сработали.
гуглил - не нашел ответа

Comment: Надо кнопки вынести в отдельный слой. 
Вот так примерно
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1010917/281715

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:title="This is toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"
    app:subtitleTextColor="?colorPagerYellow"
    app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
    app:titleTextColor="?colorPagerYellow" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="This is Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```